# Duplicity Trailing Backup Configuration

Tags: backup, duplicity

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can configure Duplicity to work in a specific way.

I'm planning to send backups to BackBlaze B2.

I would like to create a sort of trailing backup of 30 days. So at any time I would like that there is 30 days of incremental daily backups available. Here is my plan (the ideal situation):

```
Day 1 - Full Backup
Day 2 - Incremental (Delta difference backup)
.
.
.
Day 30 - Incremental (Delta difference backup)
```

What I would like is on day 31, the full backup is now somehow magically at Day 2 and incremental backups go on until day 31. So like this:

```
Day 2 - Full Backup
Day 3 - Incremental (Delta difference backup)
.
.
.
Day 31 - Incremental (Delta difference backup)
```

This is sort of like a moving backup that trails 30 days behind the current day.

While researching a solution I saw that there is an option for remove-older-than. But someone posted the output on a site I saw:

```
date = “” There are backup set(s) at time(s): Thu Apr 1 00:15:17 2010 Sun Apr 4 00:01:23 2010 Sun Apr 11 00:01:29 2010 Which can’t be deleted because newer sets depend on them. Deleting backup sets at times: Sun Apr 26 12:15:33 2009 Sun Apr 26 14:45:25 2009 Sun Apr 26 14:58:38 2009 Sun May 3 00:01:37 2009 Sun May 10 00:00:39 2009 Sun May 17 00:00:42 2009 Sun May 24 00:00:53 2009 Sun May 31 00:00:50 2009 Sun Jun 7 00:01:04 2009 Sun Jun 14 00:00:55 2009 Sun Jun 21 00:01:17 2009 Sun Jun 28 00:01:10 2009 Sun Jul 5 00:03:09 2009 Sun Jul 12 00:01:10 2009 Sun Jul 19 00:01:18 2009 Sun Jul 26 00:01:52 2009 Sun Aug 2 00:01:27 2009 Sun Aug 9 00:02:39 2009 Sun Aug 16 00:01:52 2009 Sun Aug 23 00:01:33 2009 Sun Aug 30 00:01:42 2009 Sat Sep 5 17:23:02 2009 Sun Sep 6 00:00:41 2009 Sun Sep 13 00:00:47 2009 Sun Mar 7 00:04:47 2010 Sun Mar 14 00:07:12 2010 Sun Mar 21 00:01:36 2010 Sun Mar 28 00:02:14 2010
```

So it looks like Duplicity doesn't really delete a full backup set if something depends on it. Now I would expect that what would happen with me is there will be a Full backup that would be stored forever plus a increment file for each day forever? I don't know if that even makes sense.

So I checked out another site that seemed to suggest to use 'keep' (that I saw in a dup config file). I don't know how that one works.

For what I want to do, will I have to run two backup jobs? Say each one running for 2 months started one month apart and delete and recreate at the end of the cycles? That would at least guarantee me the 30 days at the smallest point.

There has to be a simpler way to do this. Maybe I am completely overlooking something coz I don't think I'm the first to want something like this :)

Any ideas?